# Does Using Async Always Make C++ Code Faster

Tags: c++, asynchronous

Is using async function in c++ is always a good idea?

Literally I meant many times we may need to do some simple things like making a function that returns weather a no is prime etc so does it make c++ code faster or make it more slow?

//Example Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
using namespace std;
bool AsyncTest(int n){
    //do some stuffs    
    return true;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for(int i=1;i<=10;i++){
        future<bool>ans=async(launch::async,AsyncTest,i);
        cout<<ans.get()<<endl;
    }
}
```

Thanks for reading

Comment: Nothing is a silver bullet for performance. In your code example, you're undoubtedly slowing the program down by launching an asynchronous operation and then blocking on it immediately each iteration.

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: If this was true, every compiler vendor would implement it like this and we wouldn't know/care.

Comment: The code in the question will never be faster than the obvious implementation. Firing off a new task and immediately waiting for it to complete just adds overhead to doing the task directly. The speed benefit from `async` comes from doing something in parallel with the asynchronous task. This code doesn't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This highly depends on your situation.

I will describe a few situations.

**Situation 1:**
All tasks are very quick to handle. The sum of all the calculation time is small in comparison with the overhead you will face for creating the different threads.

-> You will gain no, very little or even negative speed increase.

**Situation 2:**
All tasks take a long time.

-> You will probably get a speed increase.

**Situation 3:**
One task takes long, the others are very quick.

->You will probably get no speed increase, since it doesnt matter, if you calculate the other tasks in parallel.

**Situation 4:**
The tasks need a shared resource (e.g. file access)

->You will probably get no speed increase, since all tasks have to wait in order to get exclusive access to the shared resource.

**Conclusion:**

There are many more scenarios that can occur. Thus, in order to archive a speed increase you have to

- measure where your hot spot in your code using real world test cases (use a tool such as perf or vTune)
- identify a way to parallelize the hot spot.
- measure again

Comment: To add to situation 2, you still need to be careful of false sharing.  That could slow the code right back down to serial speed if you are not careful.

Answer (score 3):

There's very little that is *always* a good idea.

In particular, using something that you are not familiar with (and unwilling to become familiar enough with to answer the question yourself) is invariably a bad idea.

Programmers make many more mistakes when they are using unfamiliar techniques.  What is "best" depends on the team implementing it as well as technical considerations.

Answer (score 1):

Doing anything with multi-threading requires more work than single threaded. It requires synchronisation routines and thread creation etc... reason why multithreading can be faster is because while multithreading more hardware, like CPU cores, can be used at the same time.

So you think that adding more work and overhead will necessarily improve performance of the program?